# Identify a sequence of numbers written as words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have lists of words in python. In the list elements I have numbers written as words. For example:

```
list = ['man', 'ball', 'apple', 'thirty-one', 'five', 'seven', 'twelve', 'queen']
```

I have also the dictionary with every number written as word as the key and the corresponding digit as value. For example:

```
n_dict = {'zero':0, 'one':1, 'two':2, ...., 'hundred':100}
```

What I need to do is to identify let's say 4 or more (greater than 4) numbers written as words consecutively in the list and convert them to digits based on the dictionary. For example *list* should be like:

```
list = ['man', 'ball', 'apple', '31', '5', '7', '12', 'queen']
```

However, if there are less consecutive elements than the number specified (in our case 4) the list shall be the same. For example:

```
list2 = ['bike', 'earth', 't-shirt', 'twenty-five', 'zero', 'seven', 'home', 'bottle']
```

*list2* Shall remain as it is.

In addition, if there are multiple sequences with numbers written as words but they are not reaching the minimum amount of consecutive words required the words should not change to digits. For example:

```
list3 = ['stairs', 'tree', 'street', 'forty-two', 'nine', 'submarine', 'two', 'eighty-five']
```

*list3* Shall remain as it is.

The sequence of numbers written as words can be anywhere at the list. At the beginning, at the end, somewhere in the middle.

What I have tried so far:

```
def checkConsecutive(l): 
    return sorted(l) == list(range(min(l), max(l)+1))

def replace_numbers(word_list, num_dict):

    flag = False

    intersect = list(set(word_list) & set(n_dict.keys()))

    intersect_index = [word_list.index(elem) for elem in intersect]

    flag = check_if_consecutive(intersect_index)

    if (len(intersect_index) > 4) & flag:
    
       flag = True
       for index in intersect_index:
        
         word_list[index] = n_dict[word_list[index]]

return word_list, flag
```

I need to return the flag as well to keep track which of the lists changed.

The above code works fine but I think it's not that efficient. My question is whether can be implemented in a better way. E.g. using [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) or something in a similar fashion.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what is your question? Stack Overflow is not meant to just provide code; you need to ask a specific problem about a specific problem.

Comment: I am sorry @M-Chen-3. I have not made many posts so I already considered my code was too ugly to post. I edited the post.

Comment: I am sorry @Aven Desta. It is not a homework, it is part of a problem I am trying to solve and I converted it to this kinda list handling operation. As I mentioned above I considered my code too ugly to post.

Answer (score 0):

For digits

```py
from itertools import filterfalse
list_of_strings_that_are_secretly_integers = [*filterfalse(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool), (n_dict.get(i, False) for i in list_of_strings))]
```

For consecutivity, the following should work for any indexed candidate

```py
def continuous(candidate, differential=1):
    return all(e == candidate[i-1] + differential for i, e in enumerate(candidate[1:]))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the spirit of the answer that I was looking for. However, this does one part of the job since it returns the digits but does not check if the digits where consecutive in the list i.e. it does not check the indexes in the list of the strings to be consecutive